# AWS Amplify signInWithWebUI with custom username

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my app I use AWS Amplify to handle user authentications.
The user can register manually or using external sources like Google of Facebook for which I use `Amplify.Auth.signInWithSocialWebUI`.
If the user regisers manually, he can add custom username, if it is via Google or Facebook, it is random string e.g. Facebook_213218587329.

Is there a way to pass a custom username via the `signInWithWebUI`?